# Swift 3 Core Data - How to save context synchronously?

Tags: swift, core-data

I need to import data into one enity, and then another entity that has a relationship with the first. The problem is that it crashes on the second entity because the the save is not complete on the first. How should I best deal with this in Swift 3 / Xcode 8 / IOS 10?

```
self.viewContext.save()
```

I need to make sure the save is complete before importing the second entity.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that it was saving synchronously, but I had to save after each row, otherwise it was just not working.